# AWS EMR - Spark submit pyspark job with --archive including the entrypoint

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, spark-submit

I am trying to find a way to package a pyspark project in such a way that I can include the entry point in the archive and refer to it in my spark-submit command. I have tried this:

```
aws emr add-steps --cluster-id j-XXXXXXXXXX \
--steps '[{
        "Args":
        ["spark-submit",
            "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
            "--archives", "s3://bucket/myarchive.tar.gz#venv",
            "--conf", "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./venv/bin/python",
            "./venv/main.py",
        ],
        "Type": "CUSTOM_JAR",
        "ActionOnFailure": "CONTINUE",
        "Jar": "command-runner.jar",
        "Properties": "",
        "Name": "Test"
    }
]' \
--region us-east-1
```

But the step errors out, not being able to find the main.py (that is in the root of the tar.gz file).

This works great if I point to a main.py in S3 (I just use the method described [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/emr-serverless-samples/tree/main/examples/pyspark/dependencies)).

So, I take it "." in the "--conf" section is not the same as the "." OR the archive is not uncompressed everywhere I need it to?

I just want a method that will not involved keeping an archive and an entry point per project. I'd like to have one archive, one project.